# Subsequence with a limit

Tags: list, debugging, prolog, dcg, subsequence

This is my problem:

> Write a procedure `distance(List, Nemptylist, SubList)/3` that checks if `Sublist`
>   is a sublist of `List` with a distance of not more than `N` between items constraint (`N`
>   is implemented as `Nemptylist` – a list of `N` anonymous variables). Assume that `List`
>   is fully instantiated. Duplicate answers are allowed, as long as their number is finite.
>
> For example, for `N` = 2 :
>
> ```
> ?- distance( [a,t,d,r,a,n,c,b,c] , [_,_], [a,b,c] ).
> true
>
> ?- distance( [m,a,t,d,r,b,c,t] , [_,_] , [a,b,c] ).
> false
>
> ?- distance([a, t, d, r, a, n, c, b], [_, _], [a, b, c]).
> false
>
> ?- distance([c, c, c, a, c, c, c], [_, _], [a]).
> true.
> ```

I've been sitting for hours, trying to solve this problem and eventually the examples
above worked, but then i ran some tests and they failed.

My solution for now is as follows:

```
distance( L1 , L2 , [X]   ) :-
  member(X,L1) .
distance( L1 , L2 , [H|T] ) :-
  distance(L1,L2,T) ,
  append(Y,Z,L2) ,
  T=[Hs|Ts] ,
  append([H],Y,W) ,
  append(W,[Hs],R) ,
  sublist(R,L1) .

prefix(X,L) :- append(X, _, L).

suffix(X,L) :- append(_, X, L).

sublist(X,L) :- suffix(S,L) , prefix(X,S) .
```

when i try to run this test:

```
distance( [r,a,n,c,b,c],[],X) .
```

it fails due to run-time exceeded error.

I debugged it for hours and I'm really exhausted. Please help me finish this horrible assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two major problems with your implementation:

1. **You are unifying elements from `NEmptyList` with elements from `List`** in the `sublist(R, L1)` goal. Future `sublist` goals might fail as `NEmptyList` will not unify with any `N` consecutive elements from `List`. If you want to use append (which is ok), you should build a new list of length at most `N` every time (see below).
2. You might **validate different sequences from `SubList` with the same unique sequence from `List`**. To demonstrate this, try this with your solution:

   ```
   ?- distance([a,a],[],[a,a,a,a,a,a]).
   true ;
   true ;
   false.
   ```

Here is a solution:

```
distance(_, _, []).
distance(List, NEmpty, Sublist):-
    append(_, Right, List),   % The first element can be anywhere in the list
    distance2(Right, NEmpty, Sublist).

distance2([X|_], _, [X]).
distance2(List, NEmpty, [X|Sublist]):-
    length(NEmpty, N),
    between(0, N, N1),
    length(AtMostNEmpty, N1), % Make a different list each time of length <N
    append([X|AtMostNEmpty], Right, List),
    distance2(Right, NEmpty, Sublist).
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution step-by-step starting with an incomplete definition:

```
distance_tentative(Xs, _Ys, Zs) :-
   phrase(( ..., seq(Zs), ... ), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... .

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).
```

This solution is too specialized because it describes only [substrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) but not [subsequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence). A subsequence is rather:

```
subseq([]) --> [].
subseq([E|Es]) --> [E], subseq(Es).
subseq(Es) --> [_], subseq(Es).
```

Now, we want to limit the number of intermediary unrelated elements. That is, we want to limit the application of the last rule to the length of this list argument `LN`.

```
subseq_n([], _) --> [].
subseq_n([E|Es], LN) --> [E], subseq_n(Es, LN).
subseq_n(Es, [_|LN]) --> [_], subseq_n(Es, LN).
```

Maybe the last rule should rather read:

```
subseq_n(Es, [E|LN]) --> [E], subseq_n(Es, LN).
```

I suspect some problem in the translation of the problem statement. In any case, now we have:

```
distance(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
   phrase(( ..., subseq_n(Zs, Ys), ... ), Xs).
```

There are many redundant answers, but you stated that this is OK.

### Optimizations

There is a lot of redundancy that is, ambiguity, between the first `...` and the start of the first element of `subseq_n//2`; similarly, between `subseq_n//2` and `...` at the end. Further, if `Zs` is empty, a single answer would suffice. Brief

```
distance(_Xs, _Ys, []).
distance(Xs, Ys, [Z|Zs]) :-
   phrase( ( ..., [Z], rsubseq_n(Zs, Ys), ... ), Xs).

rsubseq_n([], _) --> [].
rsubseq_n([E|Es], Ys) --> [E], rsubseq_n(Es, Ys).
rsubseq_n([E|Es], [_|Ys]) --> [_], rsubseq_n([E|Es], Ys).
```

Note that the "distance list" is now used only within the subsequence.

This program has very favorable termination properties:

> [`distance(A,B,C)terminates_if b(A).`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cti/cgi/cti?texta=distance%28_Xs%2C+_Ys%2C+%5b%5d%29.%0D%0Adistance%28Xs%2C+Ys%2C+%5bZ|Zs%5d%29+%3A-%0D%0A+++phrase%28+%28+...%2C+%5bZ%5d%2C+rsubseq_n%28Zs%2C+Ys%29%2C+...+%29%2C+Xs%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Arsubseq_n%28%5b%5d%2C+_%29+--%3E+%5b%5d.%0D%0Arsubseq_n%28%5bE|Es%5d%2C+Ys%29+--%3E+%5bE%5d%2C+rsubseq_n%28Es%2C+Ys%29.%0D%0Arsubseq_n%28%5bE|Es%5d%2C+%5b_|Ys%5d%29+--%3E+%5b_%5d%2C+rsubseq_n%28%5bE|Es%5d%2C+Ys%29.%0D%0A%0D%0A...+--%3E+%5b%5d.%0D%0A...+--%3E+%5b_%5d%2C+...+.)

So only the first argument has to be known to make the predicate terminate.

Edit: Your problem statement has been ambiguous w.r.t. where the distance `N` applies to:

> ... with a distance of not more than N between items constraint ...

This can mean a total edit distance of no more than N, or a distance between each consecutive pair. So assuming that the distance between each consecutive pair is meant:

```
distanceII(_Xs, _Ys, []).
distanceII(Xs, Ys, [Z|Zs]) :-
   phrase( ( ..., [Z], rsubseq_d(Zs, Ys), ... ), Xs).

rsubseq_d([], _) --> [].
rsubseq_d([E|Es],Max) -->
   maxseq(Max),
   [E],
   rsubseq_d(Es, Max).

maxseq(_) --> [].
maxseq([_|Es]) --> [_], maxseq(Es).
```